# How to increase all the prices which is dict values by 10%

Tags: python, dictionary

How do we increase all prices in menu which the values by 10%.

**Code:**

```
burger = {'Fiery Pepper' : 5.65,'McSpicy':'4.85','Quarter Pounder':'4.20','Cheeseburger':'2.35'}
beverages = {'Hot Tea':2.60,'McCafe':2.70,'Coca-Cola':2.65}
menu ={}
menu.update(burger)
menu.update(beverages)
for key in sorted(menu):
    print(key, '->', menu[key]
```

Comment: @karthikr .update multiply 1.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply them by **`1.1`** (or **110%** of original):

```
burgers = {k: float(v) * 1.1 for k, v in burgers.items()}
beverages = {k: float(v) * 1.1 for k, v in beverages.items()}
```

Comment: is this in a new line?

Comment: some of the values are `str`, do you think `float(v)` is needed?

Comment: @hjpotter92 why does in meant by these two sentence? Is there other way to do it?